# POSTGRESQL Query and insert based on results

Tags: postgresql, psql

In this case I'm trying to perform a SELECT based query followed by an insert of new records into the same table based on those results. For example a simple table:

```
Table "samples"

Fields: 
      id   unique
      name 
      locations
      randoma
      randomb
      randomc
```

To be clear my objective from the selection is to create a new sample with a given name and id for each location, but the rest of the fields can be left to default. This is the selection portion:

```
SELECT locations FROM samples WHERE name = 'example';
```

The command chain below works for a single record, but I need the query and creation to be iterative. Aforementioned attempt:

```
INSERT INTO samples (nextval('my_sequence'), 'newsample', (SELECT locations FROM samples WHERE name = 'example');
```

I've haven't found a solution yet and would appreciate any admonishment on this PSQL simplicity.

I realize that this is a poor example in terms of database normalization, but it's merely for effect.

Best regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insert` syntax is incorrect, it should look like `insert into <table> select <something> from <table>` -- not like `insert into <table> (something, something, (select ...`. And don't sprinkle parentheses at random -- they are meaningful.

```
INSERT INTO samples 
  SELECT nextval('my_sequence'), 'newsample', locations 
  FROM samples WHERE name = 'example'
```